# Difference between neutron degeneracy pressure and thermal pressure of a neutron star

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, neutron-stars

I'm solving TOV (Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff) equations and i'm just confused in first equation of TOV equations. The pressure involved in TOV equations is a thermal pressure or neutron degeneracy pressure?

Answer (score 2):

The pressure is just the total pressure. You do not make any distinction about the source of that pressure. The distinction between thermal pressure and degeneracy pressure is in any case false; they are merely two extreme cases of a single density- and temperature-dependent function.

In an actual neutron star, neutron degeneracy pressure would be insufficient to support its weight in General Relativistic conditions. It has been known since the 1930s that the maximum mass that could be supported by ideal neutron degeneracy pressure is about 0.7 solar masses. All measured neutron star masses are larger than this.

The dominant source of pressure is likely to be the repulsive strong nuclear force between neutrons when they are squeezed together closer than a femto-metre.